# Promoted Links Background Image Won't Update

Tags: sharepoint-online, image, promoted-links

I have a Promoted Links webpart on the landing page for an enterprise Team Site.  I uploaded custom background images, linked to them from the Promoted Links Library, and everything was working fine.

Unfortunately I needed to make changes to two of the images.  After uploading the images and re-linking in the Promoted Links library, the original images still appear as the background in both the library and in the webpart on the landing page.

Things I've tried so far:

- Deleted the original images.  They still appear.
- Renamed the new images, re-uploaded and re-linked them.  The original (deleted!) images still appear.
- Deleted the library.  Recreated it with a different name. Re-built everything using different names.  The original (deleted!) images still appear.
- Checked out the new images.  Checked them back in.  The original (deleted!) images still appear.

I don't currently have access to the top level site collection to empty the recycle bin.  That's probably my next step.  I'm also waiting on a re-index of both the Promoted Links library and the library containing the images.

Other than that I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?

Comment: Strange behavior. Check if it is an IE caching issue.

Comment: Hi @Frank Potrafky, Welcome to SE community, we have converted your answer to a comment because it's flagged as a Low-Quality Answer, More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @FrankPotrafky - Good call, but I loaded the page in Chrome and a few other browsers and got the same results.  I dumped all the IE browsing history, cookies, etc. just to be sure.  Same results.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed likely a caching issue, as it was hinted in the comments. It may be the browser's cache, or SharePoint's cache. Both have a limited lifetime, and clearing browser's cache would be the simple first step to take. Having a look at SP's recycle bins is also recommended, as you are about to do. Additionally, confirm the following things:

- Do other users also see the old images?
- Does it occur with different browsers when you are viewing the Promoted Links?

If the behavior varies between approaches/users, the image has been successfully changed and is just temporarily showing wrong in your particular scenario.

One more thing you can do is to inspect the Promoted Link's element, and see the source of the used image as shown in the HTML. This can be done with the browser's developer tools. If the source of the image points to the original location where you used to store the old images, it's yet another suggestion that the reference is just shown from the cache. However, if the source comes from elsewhere, that'd suggest there's something wrong likely with the Promoted Links itself. Cases like these should be handled with Microsoft directly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  I checked the image using Chrome's developer tools, and found the image link points to the correct (new) image.  I've also tested the page using a separate user "test" account and had the same results.  I'll take your advice and try to track down an answer through Microsoft as well.